# How to manage nested structures in ctypes?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, ctypes

I have a C++ library with following union:

```
typedef union DVersion
{
    uint32_t VMask;
    struct
    {
        uint8_t Build;
        uint8_t Rev;
        uint8_t Min;
        uint8_t Maj;
    };
}DATA_VER;
```

And another structure with a field that contains this one

```
typedef struct DH
{
    uint16_t   Tok1;
    DATA_VER   DVersion;
    uint16_t   DataCount;
}DataHeader
```

When I use this dll on C++ it works perfectly, also on C#. So the DLL is verified.

When I work on Python using ctypes it looks like the amount of bytes don't correspond.

I've tried these solutions

**Solution 1:**

```
class VER_Struct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("Build", c_uint8),
                ("Rev",  c_uint8),
                ("Min",  c_uint8),
                ("Maj",  c_uint8)]

class DATA_VER(Union):
    _anonymous_ = ("u",)
    _fields_ = [("VMask", c_uint32, 32), 
                ("u",VER_Struct)]

class DataHeader(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("Tok1", c_uint16, 16),
                ("DVersion", DATA_VER),
                ("DataCount", c_uint16, 16)]
```

**Solution 2:**

```
class DATA_VER(Union):
    _fields_ = [("VMask", c_uint32, 32), 
                ("Build", c_uint8),
                ("Rev",  c_uint8),
                ("Min",  c_uint8),
                ("Maj",  c_uint8)]

class DataHeader(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("Tok1", c_uint16, 16),
                ("DVersion", DATA_VER),
                ("DataCount", c_uint16, 16)]
```

In both cases, Tok1 has the correct value, but DVersion and DataCount are not displaying correctly. Looks to me that the bytes are misaligned because of the nested structure.

Could you hint me what am I doing wrong? Thank you so much in advanced!

Comment: Maybe checking what's padding and alignment will help?

Comment: Thank you, Do you know where could I find information about alignment on ctypes?

Comment: Glad it helped, I've never used ctypes before :) In this kind of parsers you can just remember by rule of thumb to check 2 things on interface: 1. padding , 2. endianness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found it out!

Even when is not explicit on the ctypes documentation, is good practice to include 
`_pack_ = 1` on your structures. On my case it was:

```
class VER_Struct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("Build", c_uint8),
                ("Rev",  c_uint8),
                ("Min",  c_uint8),
                ("Maj",  c_uint8)]

class DATA_VER(Union):
    _anonymous_ = ("u",)
    _fields_ = [("VMask", c_uint32, 32), 
                ("u",VER_Struct)]

class DataHeader(Structure):
    _pack_   = 1
    _fields_ = [("Tok1", c_uint16, 16),
                ("DVersion", DATA_VER),
                ("DataCount", c_uint16, 16)]
```

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Normally you only need to pack if the structure packed.  Is there a `#pragma pack` or equivalent statement in the C++/C# code?

Comment: The trouble I had was that im using an external DLL, all I have are the .H and the Dll

Comment: Normally the .H file would have the structure definition and the packing declaration if any.